# Get iterator to beginning of function-generated range within for loop

Tags: c++

I am trying to get an iterator to the beginning of a `for` loop, in which the range is generated by a function:

```
std::vector<int> buildList() {...}

int main() {
   for (const auto& i : buildList()) {
       const auto& id{ &i - RANGE_BEGIN};
   }
}
```

Is there a way to point to the beginning of the range without declaring the `vector` outside of the `for` loop?

Comment: The whole purpose of range iteration is to avoid dealing with icky iterators. You need iterators for this.

Comment: Why not simply store the reference to the vector in a variable, and get the `begin` iterator from that? What is the actual problem this is supposed to solve? This feels very much like a [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: The answer to your question: no.

Comment: This smells like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  Why is it important to you that the vector not be declared outside of the loop?

Comment: @DrewDormann: the point is to avoid polluting the code with lots of short-lived local variables that make it hard to read.

Comment: Exactly, it's about not pollution the scope. I know there are alternatives but it would be nice to have one that does not pollute.

Comment: To avoid polluting scopes, then use smaller scopes. Either move the loop into a separate function, or wrap it inside `{ }` braces. Either way, you can then limit your temp variable(s) for the loop inside the same scope that the loop exists in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way to point to the beginning of the range without declaring the `vector` outside of the `for` loop?

No, there is not.  You must save it to a local variable in order to refer to it inside the loop body, eg:

```
int main() {
   auto theList = buildList();
   for (const auto& i : theList) {
       const auto& id{ &i - &theList[0] };
       ...
   }
}
```

But, since this code is simply calculating `id` to be an index into the `vector`, you may as well just use a separate local variable to track the index while iterating the `vector` with a `range-for` loop, eg:

```
int main() {
   size_t id = 0;
   for (const auto& i : buildList()) {
       // use id as needed...
       ++id;
   }
}
```

Otherwise, just use a traditional index-based `for` loop instead of a `range-for` loop, eg:

```
int main() {
   auto theList = buildList();
   for (size_t id = 0; id < theList.size(); ++id) {
       const auto& i = theList[id];
       ...
   }
}
```

Comment: The trouble with this idea is forgetting to increment `id` on all code paths.